# Autovacuum is not running on Openshift Online Postgres cartridge

Tags: postgresql, openshift, autovacuum

I have Postgres 9.2 on my Openshift Online cartridge.  Using Pgadmin3, I have enabled (by ticking the box) the autovuum setting for postgresql.conf.  However, the autovacuum does not seem to be running.

Here is what I have:

1. `ps -ef  | grep -i vacuum`
   No autovacuum process is shown.
2. Using psql console, `show autovacuum`, says that its value is ON
3. Using psql console, `SELECT schemaname, relname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum from FROM pg_stat_user_tables;` gives no value in last_vacuum and last_autovacuum column even though I did a manual Vacuum via Maintenance function using pgadmin3.
4. The properties tab on the db in pgAdminIII says AUTOVACUUM value of 'not running'

What do I miss?

EDIT
I also cannot access the postgresql.conf on Openshift Online when trying to find the file on the server - hoping to manually edit the file instead of using pgAdminIII.
-- Found this `https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-do-i-set-maxpreparedtransactions-on-my-postgresql-cartridge`  I am now able to view/edit my postgresql.conf.  Apparently the autovacuum is on already so the conf has the right setting.

When issue `pg_ctl restart -m fast`  I got

```
LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Permission denied 
LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector 
LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Permission denied 
LOG: trying another address for the statistics collector 
LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector 
LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket 
WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration 
HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option. 
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-04-22 09:58:19 GMT 
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Though `track_counts` is already set to on in postgresql.conf

Sorry for being so stupid but any help or pointers are much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have no sessions in the state `<idle> in transaction`. They will prevent auto vacuum from cleaning up old values

Comment: Thank you for prompt response but how do I check that.  Not quite sure I understand what the transaction this is.  thank you.

Comment: As a superuser: `select * from pg_stat_activity`

Comment: There is no sessions with <idle> stage

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=849428

Answer (score 4):

i ran into a similar issue and found a helpful hint in [this discussion](http://tt-rss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=2912#p17162):

> ... for some *insane* reason, openshit disabled localhost, and autovacuum only connects to localhost, I suppose it makes sense that they wouldn't want to be trying to vacuum a remote db... but openshit breaks autovacuum.

one solution i've found (and that i'll probably use) is to manually add a cronjob that does a forced vacuum. [here](https://github.com/bilderbuchi/tiny_tiny_rss-openshift-quickstart/commit/4a8318be6df40cc48bfab62b2a198a20458ef4a5) is a batch-script that looks promising but be careful with the side-effects that a forced vacuum might involve (depending on you app of course).

Comment: i suffering from same problem but it does'nt solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Patching postgres to use the `OPENSHIFT_PG_HOST` environment variable instead of `localhost` seems to solve the problem: [pgstat.patch](https://github.com/liberapay/openshift-cartridge-postgres/blob/cb8842a153b0b1fc76105693b6af833543bc0d85/versions/9.4.5/patches/pgstat.patch).